# create SVN user with limited access to files

Tags: svn, ubuntu-20.04

I am working on a project and I have some confidential files stored in SVN I want to give access to another user so that we can work in coloration but I don't want that user to have access to one of the SVN directories where I have stored my files.

How do I create a user that can only access a particular repository in SVN.

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS.

Comment: Have you tried to setup path based authorization. To read more how to do the same refer https://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz.html